# Flutter custom widget positioning with other widget

Tags: flutter

I want to active left text based on right side slider position with dot line and background image will also resized based on slider height. How to implement this type of design?

Comment: I think it could be possible with a stateless widget. Give me a few mins ill get back to you, could you attach what you've already done to speed up the process?

Comment: Tried many ways but couldn't able to make any progress yet.

Comment: No problem, giving it a shot but again anything u tried that didn't work would help us not repeat those methods too.

Comment: oka so i just finished, it will take some fine tuning but functionality is there will upload answer please check it out.

Comment: did you worked with dot line  in your implimention?

Comment: oh sorry i haven't, its the rest of it i didnt notice the line

Comment: for the line it should just be a matter of adding box decoration to the top of the container.

Comment: i've managed to add a line but not a dotted one, surely there should just be a way to do it online but i already spent alot of time on this. I've adjusted the ratio's abit to make it work better, please review the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically i created a Widgets wrapped in Expanded and manipulated the flex for the image height, the text_height was just a matter of array manipulation. Just add the below widget to your code to implement the functionality.

```
class HeightAdjust extends StatefulWidget {
  const HeightAdjust();

  @override
  _HeightAdjustState createState() => _HeightAdjustState();
}

class _HeightAdjustState extends State<HeightAdjust> {
  int minBoxFlex = 5;
  int imageFlex = 7;
  int selectedHeight = 4;
  List heights = [
    "4'8",
    "5'0",
    "5'2",
    "5'4",
    "5'6",
    "5'8",
    "5'10",
    "6'0",
    "6'2",
    "6'4"
  ];
  double sliderVal = 4;

  List<Widget> generateWidgets() {
    List<Widget> widgetList = [];
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (i == selectedHeight) {
        widgetList.add(Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Text(
            heights[i].toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 25),
          ),
        ));
      } else {
        widgetList.add(Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Text(
            heights[i].toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ));
      }
    }
    widgetList.add(Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: SizedBox(),
    ));
    return widgetList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: generateWidgets(),
              )),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    flex: minBoxFlex,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                Expanded(
                    flex: imageFlex,
                    child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid))),
                  child: Image.network(
                    "https://icon2.cleanpng.com/20180326/bcq/kisspng-silhouette-person-clip-art-gentleman-5ab87db0af3d46.6510984815220402407178.jpg",
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            ),
            flex: 4,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: 3,
                    child: Slider(
                      value: sliderVal,
                      min: 0,
                      max: 9,
                      divisions: 9,
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          sliderVal = newValue;
                          print(newValue);
                          selectedHeight = newValue.toInt();
                          imageFlex = newValue.toInt() + 3;
                          minBoxFlex = 12 - imageFlex;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: SizedBox())
              ],
            ),
            flex: 1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: will let you know after checking

Comment: hey just changed the BoxFit for the image from cover to fitHeight, it works better with that attribute for the image i used

Comment: hey it's been over 30 mins, could you give me an update? or verify and upvote the answer if it worked?

Comment: sry for late. jaison your code have error. Image.network is child of who?  can you please check?

Comment: Yep, while editing the code to add the line i copied border without the parent Boxdecoration, I fixed it though it should work now